# Parse String to Integer/Long/Float/Double

Tags: java, type-deduction

I'm trying to properly parse string representation of number.
Parser provides me with numeric value Integer/Long/Float/Double however when i try to parse with NumberFormat like :

```
String number = "1.0";
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().parser(number);
```

It returns a Long type. However when i try to parse "1.1" it properly deduce Double (Why not float?).
Should i write my own number parser or there is a possibility to tweak it the way that it will properly deduce types. Integers as Integers (not Long). Float as Float (not Double). Long as Long and Double as Double.

Comment: What would you need this for? If you parse a String, you will want to assign it to something... so what's the type of the variable you want to assign it to?

Comment: 1.0 is double in java. For float you must use 1.0f representation

Comment: If you parse a string using NumberFormat it will return a Number instance. After that you can type check if Number instanceof Integer/Long/Float/Double. Then after that you know what kind of Number it is so you can call Number.intValue() and so on. I know how to do this and it's working. I just need to tweak it so it parse properly. I saw DecimalFormat with custom parser rules, but it's a last resort.

Comment: @user2207495, First what kind of number format you need? if it just a matter of the decimal or not then you should be fine with double and long and no need to worry about the rest!! then it become very simple and if the use case is specific like currency or percentage and many more then you should dig more in the `NumberFormat` class other wise it's fine to use the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use java's built in number parsers?

`Double.parseDouble()`
`Float.parseFloat()`
`Integer.parseInt()`

and so on...

edit:

After looking at your comment you can try using this

```
    String number = "1.0";
    if (isInteger(number)) {
        //parse Int
    } else if (isDouble(number)){
        //parse Double
    }
```

and the methods:

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isDouble(String s) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isFloat(String s) {
    try {
        Float.parseFloat(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Because I don't know the type. It's a String.

Comment: You can use instanceof

Comment: ah nvm. I see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can try making methods and then catch `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Parsing by throwing and catching exception is a no go. As i said in comment above i know how to parse it without throwing exception or parsing it manually. NumberFormat is for that. I just want to tweak NumberFormat to act properly.

Comment: Is 1.0 a float or a double?